# How to set the prompt and tab-title on Gnome-Shell (Gnome 3, centos 7)

Tags: centos, terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal

This is embarrassing, but I don't seem to be able to set the command-prompt or the shell title. I'm using Gnome3 on centos 7.

**PROMPT**

I've added the following to ~/.bashrc:

```
export PS1="\w \$ "
```

The prompt stays the same:

```
echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

I've also tried updating the ~/.bashrc without the export:

```
PS1="\w \$ "
```

Same result.

It is almost like something is overriding it.

**TITLE**

As for the title I've tried the following:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;hi\007"
```

It doesn't take effect.

Comment: is there a .env file in your home folder that has `PS1` in it?

Comment: @MaxVernon no .env.  I rebooted the machine and now my terminal prompt shows what i expect "\w \$" However I still cannot set my title.  Although there are no .env file there is a .config folder.

Comment: I use `printf "\033]0;hi\007"` embedded in a little function: `title () 
{ 
    printf "\033]0;${1}\007"
}
`

Comment: @ericx Thanks but that doesn't work either.  It is really frustrating...i use it on osx and ubuntu not sure why it is so stubborn on gnome 3 - clearly the fault lies with the user :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I had to do in my .bashrc

```
export PS1="\\n[\\!. \\t - \\w]\\n>"

set_title() {
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;'$1'\007"'
}
```

I found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title) useful.